# Which printings of Complete Champion had this line on the Lion Totem barbarian?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, product-identification, barbarian

I have found a difference between multiple versions of the book Complete Champion.

Some appear to have the text

> Regal and intimidating, the powerful lion is a symbol of nobility among the races of the wild. By selecting him as your spiritual totem, you gain the pounce (MM313) ability at Level 3.

Others appear to have the text

> Regal and intimidating, the powerful lion is a symbol of nobility among the races of the wild. By selecting him as your spiritual totem, you gain the pounce ability (MM 313).

Which of these is actually canonically true/most recent? Which printings am I actually looking at?

I found the former version in a couple of Xerox'ed pages I had from a friend before I got the book myself and found the latter version.

Comment: [Book Nerd] Broadly, a *printing* leaves text unchanged. You can tell which printing of a book you have by the number line on the title page: it'll have a list like `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`. That's the first printing. Then the lowest number's lopped off when the book's reprinted. A book's title page that says `9 8 7 6 5` is its fifth printing. A new *edition* changes text or format and restarts the print numbering at `1`. (For example the premium *PH* (2012) is a new edition—changed text, new number line—, but the premium *MIC* (2013) is only a new printing of the old.) [/Book Nerd]

Comment: @HeyICanChan What does the 10th printing look like?

Comment: @KRyan The publisher starts a new number line. For example, my U. S.-printed Penguin copy of Steinbeck's *The Pearl* has a number line that starts at `30` and ends at `22`, so it's the 22nd printing. This can vary for reazonz, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The photocopy that provided the first version has almost-certainly been altered to incorporate someone’s houserules, and does not represent *any* official publication of *Complete Champion*. There are numerous reasons to believe this:

1. It does not follow Wizard of the Coast’s formatting and style guidelines. “Level 3” is just... not how Wizards of the Coast indicated 3rd level (“3rd level” or “character level 3rd” or “3 hit dice” would all be common choices; “Level 3” is not used anywhere in the edition to my knowledge, and I pay attention to these things). For that matter, “level” is not a proper noun in their typesetting, and wouldn’t be capitalized.
2. The alternate class features in *Complete Champion* always replace a feature with something gained at the same level. The very formatting of the book’s alternate class feature section indicates this, by indicating the **Level** that the alternate class feature comes at.

   *Complete Champion* indicates 1st level for the spiritual totem alternate class feature, which makes sense since it replaces the 1st-level feature fast movement.

   So the “at Level 3” clause in the photocopy would be a contradiction with the prior statement that spiritual totem is a 1st-level alternate class feature, and with the simple fact that fast movement comes at 1st level.
3. It is **extremely** common to recommend a single-level dip of barbarian for the purposes of gaining pounce. I have seen this recommendation literally hundreds of times. And as I have said, I have never once heard of it not working because it actually requires being a 3rd-level barbarian. If there was even a single official publication of the book that indicated pounce was delayed until 3rd level, it strains belief to suggest that this would *never* have come up. The internet is certainly subject to a certain risk of groupthink, but this suggestion is just *so* common (and the option certainly has its detractors who would be glad to find any excuse to burst that bubble).
4. Finally, from a pure system-design perspective, the 1st-level pounce option is really important to the game. Prior to *Complete Champion* and this option, melee characters basically could not move and maintain their damage; existing options to do it were just far too expensive. While it is problematic to effectively “patch” this situation in a splatbook, and it’s even more problematic to tie the patch specifically to one of two classes (*Complete Champion* also includes Travel Devotion, best used by clerics, which also improves this situation), but ultimately the game is better *with* these options, imperfect as they are, than it was without them. Doesn’t necessarily mean that’s what Wizards of the Coast *intended*, but it’s a good reason to follow the second version *regardless* of their intent. And since *Complete Champion* was a rather-late book, and this wasn’t the only such fix it included, I think there is reason to think they knew exactly what they were doing.

Comment: Actually, this is not universally true. The Ranger ACF  Solitary Hunting replaces animal companion, but is active from level 1.

Comment: @WeckarE. Good point. But *Complete Champion*’s ACFs are always on the same level as what they replace, since they use the formatting with the separate **Level**. Unfortunately, WotC was not very consistent about ACFs, variant class features, variant classes, substitution levels, and so on; they all have subtle distinctions that even they didn’t always keep straight, and they don’t always work *precisely* the same in each book they appear in.

Comment: Well, there's the thing: Either version says that they replace fast movement, but one of them explicitly states you don't gain the replacing ability until level 3 (ability-syntactically not that strange). But I see your point.

Comment: Seriously, that capital L in *Level* really is a dead giveaway in denying that text's legitimacy. That's *just not done*, and it hurts my eyes to see it.

Comment: (For those interested, a printing/edition conversation about the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* occurs [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?526338-What-does-your-copy-of-FRCS-p-61-say-under-quot-building-a-portal-quot-Errata-confirmed). It raises some interesting (for some quantities of *interesting*) questions about the accuracy (therefore validity) of certain PDFs as well as changes made in non-U. S.  printings.)